# Shuffle.js - filter images on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are 2 tabs (data-groups) - Graphics and Logo, with images, each one has 3 images, total 6 images. The filter works well, when you click first tab, it becomes active and shows 3 images filtered and belong to first data-group (Graphics). But when you refresh page, you see first active tab (data-group Graphics) as well, but showing all 6 images, which is wrong. Filter starts working only when you click the tab. It should show only 3 of them matched by data-group. I've tried several scripts and solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552403/filter-images-with-a-button-on-page-load?newreg=77ee8c51cf2d495ab6383426649eeb4c). Nothing worked. Any solution?

```js
function portfolio_init() {
  var portfolio_grid = $('#portfolio_grid'),
    portfolio_filter = $('#portfolio_filters');

  if (portfolio_grid) {

    portfolio_grid.shuffle({
      speed: 450,
      itemSelector: 'figure'
    });

    $('.site-main-menu').on("click", "a", function(e) {
      portfolio_grid.shuffle('update');
    });


    portfolio_filter.on("click", ".filter", function(e) {
      portfolio_grid.shuffle('update');
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#portfolio_filters .filter').parent().removeClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      portfolio_grid.shuffle('shuffle', $(this).attr('data-group'));
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Portfolio Subpage -->
<section class="pt-page pt-page-4" data-id="portfolio">
  <div class="border-block-top-110"></div>
  <div class="section-inner">
    <div class="section-title-block">
      <div class="section-title-wrapper">
        <h2 class="section-title">Portfolio</h2>
        <h5 class="section-description">Works</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Portfolio Content -->
    <div class="portfolio-content">

      <!-- Portfolio filter -->
      <ul id="portfolio_filters" class="portfolio-filters">
        <li class="active">
          <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link active" data-group="graphics">Graphics</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="logo">Logo</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="print">Print</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="billboards">Billboards</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="misc">Misc</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="photo">Photo</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- End of Portfolio filter -->

      <!-- Portfolio Grid -->
      <div id="portfolio_grid" class="portfolio-grid portfolio-masonry masonry-grid-3">

        <!-- Portfolio 1 - Graphics -->
        <figure class="item gallery" data-groups='["graphics"]'>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/3.jpg" class="lightbox f-gallery" title="bnr 1">
            <img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
              <h5 class="name">bnr 1</h5>
              <small>Graphics</small>
              <i class="pe-7s-icon pe-7s-photo"></i>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/4.jpg" title="bnr 1"></a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/5.jpg" title="bnr 2"></a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="item gallery" data-groups='["graphics"]'>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/3.jpg" class="lightbox f-gallery" title="bnr 2">
            <img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
              <h5 class="name">bnr 2</h5>
              <small>Graphics</small>
              <i class="pe-7s-icon pe-7s-photo"></i>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/4.jpg" title="Some text"></a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/5.jpg" title="Some text"></a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="item gallery" data-groups='["graphics"]'>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/3.jpg" class="lightbox f-gallery" title="bnr 3">
            <img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
              <h5 class="name">bnr 3</h5>
              <small>Graphics</small>
              <i class="pe-7s-icon pe-7s-photo"></i>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/4.jpg" title="Some text"></a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/5.jpg" title="Some text"></a>
        </figure>
        <!-- /Portfolio 1 - Graphics -->


        <!-- Portfolio 2 - Logo -->
        <figure class="item gallery" data-groups='["logo"]'>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/3.jpg" class="lightbox f-gallery" title="logo 1">
            <img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
              <h5 class="name">logo 1</h5>
              <small>Logo</small>
              <i class="pe-7s-icon pe-7s-photo"></i>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/4.jpg" title="bnr 1"></a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/5.jpg" title="bnr 2"></a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="item gallery" data-groups='["logo"]'>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/3.jpg" class="lightbox f-gallery" title="logo 2">
            <img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
              <h5 class="name">logo 2</h5>
              <small>Logo</small>
              <i class="pe-7s-icon pe-7s-photo"></i>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/4.jpg" title="Some text"></a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/5.jpg" title="Some text"></a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="item gallery" data-groups='["logo"]'>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/3.jpg" class="lightbox f-gallery" title="logo 3">
            <img src="images/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
              <h5 class="name">logo 3</h5>
              <small>Logo</small>
              <i class="pe-7s-icon pe-7s-photo"></i>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/4.jpg" title="Some text"></a>
          <a href="images/portfolio/full/5.jpg" title="Some text"></a>
        </figure>
        <!-- /Portfolio 2 - Logo -->


      </div>
      <!-- /Portfolio Grid -->

    </div>
    <!-- /Portfolio Content -->
  </div>

</section>
<!-- /Portfolio Subpage -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, images filtered on page load. Add this code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#portfolio_filters .grph').trigger( "click" );
    });

}
// /Portfolio subpage filters
```

Also I added class "grph" here:

```
      <!-- Portfolio filter -->
  <ul id="portfolio_filters" class="portfolio-filters">
    <li class="active">
      <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link active grph" data-group="graphics">Graphics</a>
    </li>
    <li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer to the same problem, but couldn't get the solution to work, however it successfully pointed me in the right direction to finally solving it by creating a function to execute on page load:

```js
function shuffleInit (id){
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#grid').hide();
        jQuery('#'+id)[0].click();
        $('#grid').show();
  $('#'+id).trigger('click');
 });
```

```html
<body onload="shuffleInit('graphics');">
```

Remember to add IDs to the filter divs so they can be targeted by the shuffleInit() function. Note that #grid is the default shuffle.js container for the images - I added the hide and show commands to hide the visible re-shuffle animation on page load. The last click trigger line is just a cosmetic addition highlighting the button so the user can see which filter option has been applied.

This works with Bootstrap 3. Hope it helps someone!